# Why are D1V2 instances not showing up while creating a new VM instance on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Last year, same time, i created two Ubuntu instances on Azure. I got the option of selecting a D1V2 instance back then. However, i am trying to create Ubuntu 16.04 instance, but while selecting the size I am only getting DS1V2 virtual machines, which cost the same but has much lower local SSD ( on 7GB ). The D1V2 sizes dont show up at all. Anybody has any idea why the D1V2 sizes are not showing up?

Comment: Off  topic for StackOverflow. That said: Check which storage type the portal blade defaulted to. If SSD, then you'll only get the DS variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D1V2 are not using SSD's for OS disk, therefore you cannot provision D1V2 with OS disk type set as SSD, use HDD to provision D1V2.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes

Comment: Ok . But when they say 50GB local ssd is it the data disk they are talking about ?

Comment: yes, D drive on the VM, which is temporary, so not guaranteed to persist

Comment: @user2148105 You could refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/).